# Vb.Net Combobox DisplayMember

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I got a combobox ("cmb") with a dataset (Surname, Prename etc) behind it.

```
Private Sub cmb_Format (...) Handles cmb.Format
    e.ListItem.Value = row.Item("SURNAME") & " " & row.Item("PRENAME")
End Sub
```

With this method I kind of overwrite the DisplayMember.

The problem is that if I choose one listitem by the Dropdown the textfield writes BOTH (PRENAME and SURNAME) but I just want to have the SURNAME.

I tried several hours, but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not overwriting the `DisplayMember` you are overwriting the `ValueMember`.
Do:

```
e.ListItem.Text = row.Item("SURNAME") & " " & row.Item("PRENAME")
```

Comment: Thx, ill give it a try tomorrow.